# Permalink structure for two separate blogs

Tags: posts, permalinks

I have one site with two base pages - Private and Business.
Example structure

Private

- Blog
- Pricing
- Contacts

Business

- Blog (another page, not the same as for private)
- Pricing (another page, not the same as for private)
- Contacts (another page, not the same as for private)

I need a separate permalink structure for blog articles. Currently if you open Private->Blog->Hello world the structure is `http://example.com/hello-world`. Needed structure is `/private/blog/hello-world` for Private pages and `/business/blog/hello-world` for Business pages.

Comment: How are separate blogs implemented? Are they custom post types? Entirely separate WP installations?

Comment: Currently they are same installation and same post type

Comment: Then how do you distinguish between the two exactly?

Comment: There is a category for private and business, but I am not sure this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** > **Permalinks** and set:

Custom Structure: `/%category%/%postname%/`